# Leak detected issue in cassandra 3.11.1

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We are running 36 nodes cassandra cluster. Suddenly, we started seeing this error in 2 Cassandra node logs. We are also seeing fluctuation in storage available graphs for these nodes. I am unable to understand the root cause of it. Any help is appreciated.

````
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:164360] 2023-05-04 00:30:58,094 CassandraDaemon.java:228 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:164360,1,main]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:244) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemoryWriter.reallocate(SafeMemoryWriter.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemoryWriter.setCapacity(SafeMemoryWriter.java:68) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.IndexSummaryBuilder.prepareToCommit(IndexSummaryBuilder.java:250) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter$IndexWriter.doPrepare(BigTableWriter.java:524) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.prepareToCommit(Transactional.java:173) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter$TransactionalProxy.doPrepare(BigTableWriter.java:364) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.prepareToCommit(Transactional.java:173) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableWriter.prepareToCommit(SSTableWriter.java:281) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableRewriter.doPrepare(SSTableRewriter.java:379) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.prepareToCommit(Transactional.java:173) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.doPrepare(CompactionAwareWriter.java:111) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.prepareToCommit(Transactional.java:173) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Transactional$AbstractTransactional.finish(Transactional.java:184) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.CompactionAwareWriter.finish(CompactionAwareWriter.java:121) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:220) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:61) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:268) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) [apache-cassandra-3.11.1.jar:3.11.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:164909] 2023-05-04 00:31:54,573 IndexSummaryBuilder.java:115 - min_index_interval of 128 is too low for 4298508892 expected keys of avg size 64; using interval of 145 instead
ERROR [Reference-Reaper:1] 2023-05-04 00:32:02,326 Ref.java:224 - LEAK DETECTED: a reference (org.apache.cassandra.utils.concurrent.Ref$State@4f374614) to class org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory$MemoryTidy@1106289026:Memory@[7fa6ab9ec010..7fa72ad798d0) was not released before the reference was garbage collected```
````

Comment: There is an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11916 similar with your question. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: the linked issues seem to be resolved in the 3.0.7 version. I am using 3.11.1

Comment: Maybe you can open an issue in Cassadras's jira too: https://issues.apache.org/jira/login.jsp?os_destination=%2Fbrowse%2FCASSANDRA-11916

Comment: Does this link help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64672052/leak-detected-was-not-released-before-the-reference-was-garbage-collected

Comment: @LucianaOliveira The above jira is for the development of Apache Cassandra, and as such makes for a poor vehicle for support. So we shouldn't create a support ticket there.

ps: I learned this after creating this jira. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-18556

Comment: Sorry, was you. Try to configurate the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on there, and the memory warning is probably the one that concerns me the least.

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:164909] 2023-05-04 00:31:54,573 IndexSummaryBuilder.java:115
- min_index_interval of 128 is too low for 4298508892 expected keys of avg size 64; 
using interval of 145 instead
```

This warning on the index summaries is actually indicating a serious issue, although it is not seen too commonly due to the volume of data needed to trigger it, and in some scenarios the warning does not trigger - even though it has broken the index summaries.

When the index summary breaks for the table, read response times will suffer and it can be forced to start scanning sstables because the summary no longer operates. This is relatively easy to fix.

```
ALTER TABLE your_ks.your_table WITH min_index_interval = 256;
```

Which table is a bit harder, since it does not indicate which, but the partition key count which shows over 4.2bn keys should make it relatively easy to identify.

The compaction issue itself, due to the old release that you are on, along with broken summaries, its difficult to ascertain cause / effect on that one and I would recommend fixing the index summaries, patch level and then check for re-occurrences of the issue.

You need to also start adding to your operational backlog a number of tasks:

- 3.11.1 is significantly out of date, please upgrade to 3.11.15
- Java 1.8.131 is very old - please update that to a newer release.
- Start planning for an upgrade to Cassandra 4, 3.11 will no longer be community supported when Cassandra 5 is released. (https://cassandra.apache.org/_/blog/Apache-Cassandra-3.0.x-and-3.11.x-End-of-Life-Announcement.html )

Comment: I cannot understand why I am only seeing these errors in 2 out of 36 running nodes. All of them are on the same version and have the same config.

Comment: The index summary would be based primarily on the number of partition keys the node holds, although normally with RF=3 you would expect 3 nodes to show this first. Check nodetool cfstats for the partition counts, the nodes they appear on will be the ones with the highest count (for the specific table this is happening on)

Answer (score 0):

It's a new issue for me, but you can try to configurate the `Garbage Collector`.

I seperaded some important links to this process:

***Configurate:***

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsTuningGcAbout.html

***Tunning:***

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsTuneJVM.html

https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/04/11/gc-tuning.html

***Logs:***

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/troubleshooting/reading_logs.html

***Monitoring:***

https://medium.com/@mlowicki/monitoring-cassandra-garbage-collector-83c8a515e403